# Iptables tables rules being overwritten a few minutes after reboot?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-12.04

I have some rules that I would like to apply, I added the following

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptablesRules
```

to /etc/network/interfaces so that they would automatically be applied.

After a reboot they are applied but after a few minutes they are being overwritten, by the default set?

Its an Ubuntu 12.04 vps.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

--- FIXED ---

After much mulling around it turns out there was a file /etc/sysconfig/firewall which was overwriting any rules set using the /network/interfaces as well as the iptables-persistent options.

So the lesson learned is that moving from one vps provider to another isn't exactly straight forward even if its the same OS.

Comment: Do you use something like KVM *inside* that VPS? Because several such solutions come with their own set of `iptables` rules. Another option is that something related to `dnsmasq` adds rules. There is usually a pattern visible from the added rules. The only thing I can imagine is that in your case the tool that should merely add the rules actually empties the rule table before adding.

Comment: I'm not sure, I got it from fasthosts and its the basic package so there aren't any addons like plesk etc if thats what you mean. What do you mean by pattern?

Comment: Have you looked at all crontabs? What's the output of iptables -L -n -x before and after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking into your problem and it looks like there's issue with your version of Ubuntu. More specifically dealing with how pre-up and Network Manager are working. It seems a lot of people have used the *iptables-persistent* package to successfully restore rules on start up with Ubuntu 12.04.

After installing *iptables-persistent* it will ask you if you'd like to save your current rules, or create a new rule set.

Comment: Looks like this is the way forward, cheers man. One thing though, is this a different program than just iptables and if so do i need to now disable the original iptables?

Comment: No, this is just a different "restore on start-up" method. Continue to use iptables as you normally would.

Comment: Still having issues but i'm pretty certain its due to having to amend the rules slightly to work with the persistent version.

Comment: Could you pastebin any errors that you are getting?

Comment: Can't really see anything in syslog that looks relevant. I installed iptables-persistent and edited the /etc/iptables/rules.v4 as it suggest but it still reverting back to what I am assuming is the default

Comment: Not exactly the answer but sent me in the right direction.